# Подключение к Openvpn серверу без сертификатов

Tags: linux, openvpn

Как сделать так, чтобы клиент openvpn, подключался к серверу, просто установив программу, прописав адресс и нажал подключиться. То есть, без всяких там сертификатов и т д?

Comment: это противоречит самой идее vpn. Несмотря на то, что коммуникации осуществляются по сетям с меньшим или неизвестным уровнем доверия (например, по публичным сетям), уровень доверия к построенной логической сети не зависит от уровня доверия к базовым сетям благодаря использованию средств криптографии (шифрования, аутентификации, инфраструктуры открытых ключей, средств для защиты от повторов и изменений, передаваемых по логической сети сообщений).

Comment: @maint, только не «идее vpn», а «идее программы openvpn». ведь «vpn» — это всего лишь «виртуальная частная сеть», абсолютно абстрактный описательный термин, не обозначающий ничего конкретного. интернет, к слову, тоже вполне подпадает под значение данного термина.

Comment: Не понятно какие именно сертификаты подразумевает автор, но если не ошибаюсь один сертификат всё же понадобится. Это сертификат сервера. А клиенты могут проходить проверку паролем. Вроде видел в руководстве и такой вариант.

Answer (score 1):

хотя работа «открытой всем ветрам» программы *openvpn* (т.е., доступной любому желающему без всяких там клиентских сертификатов, паролей и прочей «ненужной настоящим хакерам шелухи») прямо противоречит всей идеологии этой программы, судя по всему, такое можно осуществить.

например, слегка видоизменив [инструкцию, в которой изложено, как переключиться на аутентификацию по логину-паролю](http://skeletor.org.ua/?p=1571).

там предлагается следующая конфигурация программы *openvpn*, работающей в режиме сервера:

```
auth-user-pass-verify /etc/openvpn/verify.sh via-file
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
tmp-dir /etc/openvpn/tmp
script-security 2
```

если в файл проверки `/etc/openvpn/verify.sh` поместить всего одну строку

```
exit 0
```

то, по идее, программа «проглотит» любой логин/пароль. возможно, даже пустой.